# Is there a way to improve Elasticsearch performance on specific term query which spans different monthly indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on a `Spring Boot application` which needs to query a `Elasticsearch` cluster version `7.10` with monthly based indexes.
I'm experiencing some performance issues when I execute `term` queries against the cluster on a specific `keyword` with **high cardinality** without adding also a temporal range condition. Query profiler highlights that Elasticsearch needs to search through all the indexes for that specific `keyword`. Is there any way such as a hint or a configuration, like `eager_global_ordinals` for aggregation, to improve Elasticsearch performance for the search operations on specific fields (`keyword` type) of the indexes?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically to your case but in general improving cache utilization and utilizing early termination would be the two big topics to improve such a simple term queries.

I think the below doc is a good place to start improving elasticsearch performance.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html

In addition to the doc, if you don't need to get the total count, having lower track total hits let your search do early termination.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits

Comment: You're right, it's not my case, however thanks for the hint. I've already read the first link provided but without any luck.